# Changing the height of an iFrame tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to make a webpage(home page) that has a full page video when the user scrolls down. the header is a full screen slideshow, but once you scroll down, there will be a full screen video. I have tried the CSS for the iframe, and the only way i figured out how to change the height, was to use `height: 800px;` but the problem with that is that I need it to be able to be viewed on computers as well as smartphones, and the vertical margines are huge when I go to look at it on a smartphone.

```
<iframe style="
width: 100%;
height: 800px !important;
" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/itookthispartout" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid383042"></iframe>
```

Comment: Use `padding-bottom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1eozsnsb/

```html
<iframe style="width: 100%;height: 100vh;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/itookthispartout" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid383042"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CSS's @media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). It will allow you to change the sizing, whether it's the height or the padding-bottom, to be different depending on the size of the screen that the user is browsing on.